# Какова предикативная основа предложения?

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

Предложение такое: *Сейчас уже поздно ехать.*

Я хотела сравнить его с предложением: *Сейчас уже поздно, чтобы  ехать*. Кстати, наречие *слишком* здесь необязательно, у Толстого его нет.

Answer (score 2):

*Сейчас уже поздно ехать.* Предикативная основа **поздно ехать**. Такие предложения  трудны в квалификации. В данном виде  школьная практика определяет его как безличное с составным глагольным сказуемым, потому что  обратный порядок слов.

При прямом было бы двусоставным, где **ехать** - подлежащее, выраженное инфинитивом, поздно - сказуемое. Ехать сейчас (каково?)уже поздно.

Но возможно определить инфинитив и как дополнение: поздно -сказуемое, выраженное словом состояния; (поздно для чего?)ехать - дополнение.
Кстати, если придаточное заменяет позицию дополнения или подлежащего, это изъяснительное придаточное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и информацию. В этой теме есть над чем подумать. 1) Меня несколько смущает влияние порядка слов на структуру предложения. 2) Я как раз, как  и Вы, обратила внимание на то, что придаточное занимает именную, а не глагольную позицию, а это может говорить в пользу изъяснительного значения.

Comment: @Людмила, я вас правильно понял: вы трактуете это предложение и как придаточное?

Comment: Ну что Вы, это мы с Полиной сделали экскурс в исходный вопрос о типе придаточного: Сейчас уже поздно, чтобы ехать. Она никак не решится назвать его изъяснительным, но это именно так.

Comment: @Людмила, понятно.