# Грамматическая основа безличного предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Какая грамматическая основа в предложении "Хорошо быть кошкой"?

Answer (score 3):

***Хорошо быть кошкой.***

Ответить на этот вопрос нетрудно, так как всё предложение является его грамматической (предикативной) основой: ***хорошо быть кошкой.***

Интрига здесь в другом: **как определить подлежащее и сказуемое?** И вот эта задача часто решается неоднозначно, так как возможны **два варианта.**

1) **Двусоставное предложение**:  быть кошкой — подлежащее, хорошо  — составное именное сказуемое с пропущенной связкой.

2) **Односоставное безличное предложени**е: хорошо быть кошкой — осложненное составное именное сказуемое с  двумя связками. Хорошо — модальная связка, быть — глагольная связка, кошкой — именная часть.

Иногда решение задачи связывают **с порядком слов**: Быть кошкой хорошо (двусоставное предложение). Хорошо быть кошкой (односоставное предложение).

Вот только такой разбор **кажется уж очень формальным, хочется более определенных ориентиров.**

**В качестве экспериментального образца можно предложить следующий разбор.**

Если ***хорошо*** — это связка, то она должна быть модальной, а в **безличном** предложении ей следует выражать положительное состояние неназванного, но подразумевающегося **субъекта.** Кому хорошо-то? Неизвестно. Попробуем сравнить: ***Хочется стать кошкой.*** Здесь безличный глагол в безличном односоставном предложении, а **субъектом состояния** является, вероятно, сам автор или его персонаж.

Поэтому заданное предложение скорее **двусоставное**, и строится оно по принципу "предмет и его признак", ***быть кошкой*** — подлежащее с предметным значением, ***хорошо*** — положительная объективная  оценка (но  не состояние оценивающего  субъекта).

**Порядок слов не имеет значение**: предмет остается предметом, а признак — признаком, как их ни поставь. В данном случае использована **инверсия** с переносом логического ударения на первое слово.

**Примечание (другие примеры для сравнения)**

1)  ***Уже поздно ехать***. (Сравнить: Уже поздно, чтобы ехать). Предложение явно делится на две части: ***ехать*** — подлежащее, ***поздно*** — сказуемое, но школьные грамматики будут считать, что здесь разный разбор. Это предложение односоставное, а "Ехать уже поздно" двусоставное.

[Какова предикативная основа предложения?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443510/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

2) ***Было интересно прочитать эту книгу***. Вот это уже **односоставное безличное** предложение, ***было интересно прочитать*** — составное глагольное сказуемое, в роли связки предикативное наречие.

Почему? Субъект здесь подразумевается (мне), а в состав предложения входит дополнение. Поэтому **оценочное значение инфинитива в роли подлежащего отсутствует**, и инфинитив  входит в состав сказуемого.